# Lifting to create convex sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

Given a collection of points $P = \{(x_i , y_i ) \in [−5,5]^2 : i = 1,2, ... n\}$ . Each point is colored either red or blue according to the following function.

$\chi(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{Red,} \quad\text{(mod($\lfloor\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\rfloor,2) = 0$}\\
       \text{Blue,} \quad\text{(mod($\lfloor\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\rfloor,2) = 1$}\\
     \end{cases}$

Use a lifting function $\varphi: [-5,5]^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ to generate two disjoint convex sets R,B such that the function $\varphi$ maps all the red points tp the set $R\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ and all the blue points are map by $\varphi$ to the set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^k$.
How do I calculate the separation hyperplane that separates the set A and B?

Comment: Your two criteria for red and blue are the same @AvivSham . Assuming one of the equations should equal one, use phi(x) = mod(floor(||x||),2). Plot it and look for the separation(hint: it’s a constant).

Comment: You are correct I have just edited the question. Is there any way to formulate the question and solution? instead of just $\varphi(x) = mod(\lfloor\| x\|\rfloor,2)$

Comment: I don’t think you can change the formulation easily. Is there a reason that is necessary?

Comment: Nothing in particular just to make it more complete answer more than just write the reverse function.